# How did the president start reading the new director's name with mistake?

Tags: plot-explanation, spy-kids-2

In the 2002 movie, *Spy Kids 2: The Island of Lost Dreams* there's a scene where the president of the USA is about to announce the new director of the OSS:

> Now, it's my great pleasure to announce the new director of the OSS... "Gregorio... "Donnagon Giggles."

A card that has the new director's name has just one name on it (just like the name of winners in the Oscars). It's not a list of candidates or nominees. So how did the president start reading with a huge mistake?

Gregorio is the first name of one of the protagonists of the film (Gregorio Cortez).

Comment: Can you see the card? What's written on it?

Comment: The president puts his glasses on and looks down as he is saying his sentence, showing he is going to read something. Also, I think the card is showed from far being handed to the president before saying his sentence.

Comment: Isn't that because the prompter was hacked and showed the wrong name? Or am I missing the scene here?

Comment: If that was the case he wouldn't correct himself less than a second later. Also, how can someone hack a printed paper? Even if it was a digital screen Gregorio Cortez wasn't a man to reach his goals by deceiving others (unlike Donnagon Giggles). And also, a hacking always remain more than this.